# How to check iframe html file scroll is reached to bottom or not using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have below view page in asp.net MVC3,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
test test
test test
test test
test test
test test
</p>
<article border="0" >
<iframe src ="@Url.Content("~/Content/test.html")" width="100%" height="300px" id="iframeContent"></iframe>
</article>
<p>
test test
test test
test test
test test
test test
</p>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
sample data
</td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

The iframe src html file is little big, so it is having scroll. I want to check whether the html file scroll is reached to bottom or not. If it is reached to bottom, I need to do some validation.

I can able to do for entire page by using below jquery, but I could not figure out how it can be done for only iframe scroll content. Any suggestion folks?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("Bottom Reached!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$('iframe').bind('load',function(){
    var $win=$('iframe').get(0).contentWindow;
    $win.scroll(function() {
       if($win.scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           alert("Bottom Reached!");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: try adding it to docuement ready event.
mabe the iframe is not in the dom when you call the function